# Create an AD account and set password as expiring in 45 days

Tags: windows, vbscript, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I need some assistance with a line in an existing script that creates a user account and sets the password to non expiring (66048).

I am trying to modify the code so the password expiry is set to 45 days, but have not been able to find any information on how to do this.

The current line of code in the script is as follows:

```
objUser.userAccountControl = 66048  ' normal and never expires

objUser.PasswordRequired = True
objUser.SetPassword strPassword

For intLoop = LBound(aryGroups) To UBound(aryGroups)
    Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & aryGroups(intLoop))

    objGroup.Add objUser.ADsPath
```

Is there a way to alter the code in the `objUser.userAccountControl` line from **66048** to something else that will allow me to do this? Everything that I have read only points to the password being set to 'not required', 'non expiry' or 'can't change'.

I am trying to remove the process of admins having to manually change the password to 'does expire' after the script has run.

We are currently running version 2012 R2 of Windows AD.

Answer (score 1):

The `UserAccountControl` property can control whether or not a password expires, but the time until expiration is defined by when the password was last set and the password expiration time defined via [group policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277399.aspx) (usually the Default Domain Policy).

You need to remove the [`DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD` flag](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144) from the `userAccountControl` attribute, though, otherwise the password still won't expire, even with a password policy in place:

```
objUser.userAccountControl = 512
```

Comment: *"presumably you can also set it to other values"* [I don't think so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18627650/1630171).

Comment: So noted.  Thanks.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers. So are you saying that I should remove the 'objUser.userAccountControl = 66048 ' normal and never expires' line completely and that will resolve my issue?

Comment: @JamesHeathershaw No, I'm not saying that. Please read again.